# When using the Cast Companion Library how do I set the notification icon?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I noticed the icon is loaded like this `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_action_notification)` and I tried putting an icon with that name on my own resources with no luck. Is there some other way to override it other than replacing the resource on the CCL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all you need to change; make sure you provide all different resolutions under mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi.

Comment: I was hoping to share between my apps my IntelliJ module of CCL in case I make changes to it, is there a plan to maybe pass the icon to it or something?

Comment: No, there is no such plans. When you use a library in a project, it is the project that has to decide what resources it wants to replace.

Comment: I have the same issue, even I override ic_stat_action_notification drawable in my app. The Notification Icon keep showing the default one. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @BobbyTran have you tried adding your own resources with the names used by CCL? I believe it should work.